# How to get the output in cmd instead of inside the terminal of vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

the same as in this picture

[image: img]

I know the vscode in the picture is outdated, I took the pic from google

Comment: Hi, what picture ? The issue is poorly described.

Comment: you can set the `integrated terminal` or `external terminal` in the launch config

Comment: @Marco sorry i thought it uploaded the pic but since i'm new apparently i cant upload pics so i linked it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how...

in the settings search for java(or the language u r using, for me it was java).

keep scrolling until u see:Java(or your language name)>Debug>Settings:Console

and set it to externalTerminal [as in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJBK1.png)

you'll probably have to go back and set the external terminal into cmd if you want
it exactly the same as in the picture in the question

here is how:

in the settings search for terminal.

you'll find right away: Terminal>External: Windows Exec [as in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4uBZ.png)

set it to cmd by adding the location of the cmd on your pc.

and thats probably all if you had a problem feel free to leave a comment and I will look at it even after years of posting this...

if i was not dead by then...

Answer (score 0):

click on run menu, select 'start debugging'/press F5 short cut key.
(works only if you ran at least once successfully c/c++ program.)

F5 key will run exe file of your successful program file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).